# Sorting table by both column and row Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here, I want to set up a weekly planner where I will later insert plans into.

I have the columns sorted by the days of the week.(Monday, Tuesday...)
Now, I want the row to be sorted by the time.

However, with my code below. For every column, it loops through the same number of times as the number of items in my time slot.

Would appreciate it if you could give me some guidance on how I should go about fixing it such that each timeslot only appears once throughout the whole table.

The codes

```
<table class="Time Table">
  <tr>
    <th><%= "Time" %></th>
    <th><%= "Monday" %></th>
    <th><%= "Tuesday" %></th>
    <th><%= "Wednesday" %></th>
    <th><%= "Thursday" %></th>
    <th><%= "Friday" %></th>
    <th><%= "Saturday" %></th>

 </tr>
  <% @time_slots.each do |time_slot| %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
        <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Monday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
        <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Tuesday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
    <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Wednesday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
    <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Thursday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
    <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Friday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
    <td><% if time_slot.dayOfWeek = "Saturday" %><%= time_slot.startTime %><% end %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: So are there duplicates in `@time_slots`?

Comment: Here's a link to the picture if you didn't understand my question. http://i47.tinypic.com/znub03.png

Comment: Nope, I had one time_slot for each day. And it happens that in my table, they appear 6times each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you've just got it flipped around... You need something like this:

```
<% days = %w[ Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday] %>

<% days.each do |day| %>
   <td>
   <% @time_slots.select {|time_slot| time_slot.dayOfWeek == day }.each do |time_slot| %>
     <%= time_slot.startTime %><br/>
   <% end %>
   </td>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Also, you may wish to consider changing `dayOfWeek` to the more rails-y `day_of_week`, and `startTime` to `start_time`.

Comment: I think this is what I needed. However, by implementing this. I can't get the same days to go under the same column and some values are missing from the table. Can't seem to figure out where I went wrong. Here's a picture of it. http://tinypic.com/r/v2s7r4/6

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I messed up the logic - check the edit... (was making too many `<td>`s)

Comment: Forget about the values missing part, I figured that out. But when I added more values into Monday, it doesn't fall under the same column. Instead it extends further down the row.

Comment: Exactly, each day should only have one <td>, in my original example, each time slot was in one. The updated code should draw correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll move on to sorting them by time now.

Comment: You're welcome - you might want to try something along the lines of `<% @time_slots.select {|time_slot| time_slot.dayOfWeek == day }.sort {|x,y| y.time<=> x.time}.each do |time_slot| %>` (but maybe better to simply do that sort in the controller, when you find them).